# what eats my function time?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb

I encounter a difficult situation,and it is a little complicated,
please pay some attention to my description, thank you!

I developed an online game server,called doudizhu (鬥地主 in Chinese)
most Chinese know what it is about. The problem is that,
some little resource consume functions cost some ten milliseconds,
even more than one hundred at some time. These functions do not
operation the file,socket or db,just do some easy calculation.

The measure method is that, I write a class named `TimeElapseMeasure`,
logging the time at construct and destruct method, then I calculate 
the milliseconds it elapses.Here I use ACE_High_Res_Timer,
turn on the timer at construct method,off at destruct method,
then use elapsed_microseconds method to get the last microseconds,
divided by 1000 is what I want,in milliseconds.The source code
I will post below,including some little resource consume functions 
and gdb back-trace.

Generally,this game server looks like this:

- thread1:accept
- thread2:read from socket
- thread3:pack the data read from the socket,then push back to the list
- thread4:logic thread, in other way, business thread, pop from the list when not empty else sleep
- thread5:writev to socket
- thread6:db opertaion(mysql)
- thread7:main thread,just waiting

I spend much time finding where the time goes,but without any result.
Look up all backtrace in gdb,all other threads either sleep 
or just condition wait.

One more measure method,logging the time when just recvd 
the package and the time when the response package is flush out.
Some time it do last several --seconds--,amazingly yes,in seconds.
Where the time costs?

Please do some favor to me.

Here is the time cost function.The mea2 would call assert,
measuring starts after writev function returns,but still cost 
too much time,making me confused.I have proved that,here writev
just call once in every Svc_Send_Handler::write call.

```
int Svc_Send_Handler::write(void) 
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
      TimeElapseMeasure mea( "Svc_Send_Handler::write" );
      int count = 0;
#endif
    while (1) 
    {
        size_t buf_size = buf_.size();
        if ( buf_size == 0 )
        {
            break;
        }

        int iovcnt = buf_size;
        struct iovec iov[iovcnt];
        int sum_bytes = 0;

        Buffer_List currSendList;
#ifndef NDEBUG
        if( count > 1 )
        {
            assert(false);
        }
        ++count;
        std::vector<uint32_t> sendMsgId;
#endif
        for( int i = 0;i != iovcnt;++i )
        {
            Block_Buffer *send_buf = buf_.front();
            buf_.pop_front();
            if( ! send_buf )
            {
                assert(false);
                continue;
            }
            currSendList.push_back( send_buf );
            iov[i].iov_base = send_buf->get_read_ptr();
            iov[i].iov_len  = send_buf->readable_bytes();

            sum_bytes += send_buf->readable_bytes();

#ifndef NDEBUG
            size_t rd_idx_org = send_buf->get_read_idx();
            uint32_t len    = 0;
            uint32_t msgId  = 0;
            (*send_buf) >> len >> msgId;
            sendMsgId.push_back( msgId );
            send_buf->set_read_idx( rd_idx_org );
            ProcessDelayMeasure::instance()->secTillNow( msgId );
#endif
        }

        TimeElapseMeasure mea1( "Svc_Send_Handler::write bf writev" );
        int ret = ::writev(this->get_fd(), iov, iovcnt);
        TimeElapseMeasure mea2( "Svc_Send_Handler::write af writev" );
        if (ret == -1) 
        {
            ACE_DEBUG ((LM_DEBUG,
                        ACE_TEXT ("\n\n\n writev -1,errno:%d\n\n\n"),
                                errno
                          ));
            perror("writev");
            if (errno == EINTR)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                return ret;
            } 
            else
            {
                for( Buffer_List::iterator it = currSendList.begin();
                    it != currSendList.end(); ++it )
                {
                    sender_->push_block( *it );
                }
                for (Buffer_List::iterator it = buf_.begin(); it != buf_.end(); ++it)
                {
                    sender_->push_block(*it);
                }
                buf_.clear();
                handle_close();
                return 0;
            }
        } 
        else if (ret == sum_bytes)
        {
#ifndef NDEBUG
            for( int i = 0; i != sendMsgId.size(); ++i )
            {
                int msg_id = sendMsgId.at( i );
                ProcessDelayMeasure::instance()->endProcessMsg( msg_id );
            }
#endif
            for( int i = 0; i != iovcnt; ++i )
            {
                sender_->push_block( currSendList.front() );
                currSendList.pop_front();
            }
            continue;
        } 
        else
        {
            assert(false);
            size_t writed_bytes = ret, remove_count = 0;
            for (Buffer_List::iterator it = buf_.begin(); it != buf_.end(); ++it)
            {
                if (writed_bytes >= (*it)->readable_bytes()) 
                {
                    ++remove_count;
                    writed_bytes -= (*it)->readable_bytes();
                    sender_->push_block(*it);
                } else 
                {
                    (*it)->set_read_idx((*it)->get_read_idx() + writed_bytes);
                    break;
                }
            }
            std::cout << "remove_count = " << remove_count << std::endl;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < remove_count; ++i)
                buf_.pop_front();

            return ret;
        }         
    }
    return 0;
}

    Here is the measure class,just post the key method:

TimeElapseMeasure::TimeElapseMeasure( const std::string & name )
{
    _name = name;
    _timer.start ();    //ACE_High_Res_Timer
}

TimeElapseMeasure::~TimeElapseMeasure()
{
    _timer.stop ();
    ACE_hrtime_t nanoseconds;
    _timer.elapsed_time (nanoseconds);

    ACE_hrtime_t us;
    _timer.elapsed_microseconds(us);

    ACE_hrtime_t ms = us / 1000;

    if( ms > 1 )
    {
        ACE_DEBUG ((LM_DEBUG,
                    ACE_TEXT ("%t [%s] cost %Q us %Q ms\n"),
                      _name.c_str(),
                    us,
                    ms
                     ));
    }

    if( ms > 20 )
    {
        assert(false);
    }
}

void ProcessDelayMeasure::beginRecvMsg( int type )
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
    ACE_High_Res_Timer  timer;timer.start();
    _recvMsgDelay[type]  = timer;

    ACE_Time_Value atv;
    ACE_Time_Value aa   = atv.now();
    ACE_UINT64 mills    = aa.get_msec();
    _recvSec[type]      = mills;

    ACE_DEBUG ((LM_DEBUG,
                ACE_TEXT ("--------> beginRecvMsg msg:%d\n"),
                type
                ));
#endif
}

void ProcessDelayMeasure::secTillNow( int type,bool bResMsgType )
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
    int sendType = 0;
    if( bResMsgType )
    {
        sendType = type - 400000;   //4000000 is the diff between the request type from the client and response type from the server
    }
    else
    {
        sendType = type;
    }

    std::map<int,ACE_UINT64>::const_iterator ciFind = _recvSec.find( sendType );
    if( _recvSec.end() != ciFind )
    {
        ACE_Time_Value atv;
        ACE_Time_Value aa = atv.now();
        ACE_UINT64 now = aa.get_msec();
        ACE_UINT64 last = now - ciFind->second;
        ACE_DEBUG ((LM_DEBUG,
                    ACE_TEXT ("--------> secTillNow msg:%s cost: %Q \n"),
                    CUtil::msgId2Name( type ).c_str(),
                    last));

        //RES_SELECT_ROOM this would sleep some seconds,because of the business need
        //Though I increase the last variable more that 150 ms,
        //it still aborts at some time,I will cry out!
        if( last > 150 && RES_SELECT_ROOM != type )
        {
            assert(false);
        }
    }

#endif
}

void ProcessDelayMeasure::endProcessMsg( int type )
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
    this->secTillNow( type );
    int sendType = type - 400000;
    std::map<int,ACE_High_Res_Timer>::iterator ci = _recvMsgDelay.find( sendType );
    if( _recvMsgDelay.end() != ci )
    {
        ci->second.stop();

        ACE_hrtime_t us;
        ci->second.elapsed_microseconds( us );

        ACE_hrtime_t ms = us / 1000;
       if( ms > 1 )
        {
            ACE_DEBUG ((LM_DEBUG,
                        ACE_TEXT ("--------> endProcessMsg msg:%s cost: %Q ms\n"),
                        CUtil::msgId2Name( type ).c_str(),
                        ms));
        }

        //RES_SELECT_ROOM this would sleep some seconds,because of the business need
        //Though I increase the last variable more that 150 ms,
        //it still aborts at some time,I will cry out!
        if( ms > 150 && RES_SELECT_ROOM != type )
        {
            assert(false);
        }

        _recvMsgDelay.erase( ci );
    }
#endif
}
```

Because the gdb thread apply all but full is too large, I will post later if needed.
Thanks again!

google gprof result:

```
Total: 589 samples
     488  82.9%  82.9%      498  84.6% __nanosleep_nocancel
      18   3.1%  85.9%       18   3.1% __pthread_mutex_lock
      12   2.0%  87.9%       50   8.5% List::empty
      12   2.0%  90.0%       12   2.0% pthread_mutex_unlock
       8   1.4%  91.3%        8   1.4% __pthread_disable_asynccancel
       7   1.2%  92.5%       26   4.4% Mutex_Guard::Mutex_Guard
       7   1.2%  93.7%        7   1.2% std::list::empty
       4   0.7%  94.4%        4   0.7% __read_nocancel
       4   0.7%  95.1%        4   0.7% nanosleep
       3   0.5%  95.6%        4   0.7% __pthread_enable_asynccancel
       3   0.5%  96.1%        3   0.5% pthread_sigmask
       2   0.3%  96.4%      274  46.5% Logic_Manager::process_list
       2   0.3%  96.8%        3   0.5% Time_Value::operator timespec
       2   0.3%  97.1%        2   0.3% Time_Value::sec
       2   0.3%  97.5%      507  86.1% Time_Value::sleep
       1   0.2%  97.6%        1   0.2% ACE_Time_Value::ACE_Time_Value
       1   0.2%  97.8%        1   0.2% Logic_Manager::isRunning
       1   0.2%  98.0%        1   0.2% Logic_Server::instance
       1   0.2%  98.1%       19   3.2% Mutex_Guard::acquire
       1   0.2%  98.3%       14   2.4% Mutex_Guard::release
       1   0.2%  98.5%       27   4.6% Stream_Packer::process_drop
       1   0.2%  98.6%       11   1.9% Stream_Packer::split_block_process
       1   0.2%  98.8%       10   1.7% Thread_Mutex::release
       1   0.2%  99.0%        1   0.2% Time_Value::set
       1   0.2%  99.2%        1   0.2% _Hashtable_iterator
       1   0.2%  99.3%        1   0.2% __connect_nocancel
       1   0.2%  99.5%        1   0.2% cond_signal (inline)
       1   0.2%  99.7%        1   0.2% std::_Rb_tree::_S_key
       1   0.2%  99.8%        1   0.2% writev
       1   0.2% 100.0%       15   2.5% ~Mutex_Guard
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% 0x00007fffdb5fd8ef
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% 0x00007ffff372e19f
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% 0x00007ffff372e1df
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% 0x00007ffff372e99f
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% 0x00007ffff412f99f
       0   0.0% 100.0%        6   1.0% 0x00007ffff4b30c9f
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2   0.3% 0x00007ffff4b30ccf
       0   0.0% 100.0%        8   1.4% 0x00007ffff4b30d0f
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% ACE_Condition::signal
       0   0.0% 100.0%        3   0.5% ACE_Log_Msg::log@e6e00
       0   0.0% 100.0%        3   0.5% ACE_Log_Msg::log@e7410
       0   0.0% 100.0%        3   0.5% ACE_Log_Msg::log@e8b90
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2   0.3% ACE_Task_Base::svc_run
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2   0.3% ACE_Thread_Adapter::invoke
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2   0.3% ACE_Thread_Adapter::invoke_i
       0   0.0% 100.0%        7   1.2% Epoll_Watcher::loop
       0   0.0% 100.0%        3   0.5% Epoll_Watcher::process_timer_event
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2   0.3% Epoll_Watcher::watcher_loop
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2   0.3% Logic_Manager::process_100001
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% Logic_Manager::process_block
       0   0.0% 100.0%      275  46.7% Logic_Manager::run
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% Logic_Player::respond_error_result
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% Logic_Player::respond_finer_result
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% Logic_Sender::find_client
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2   0.3% LoginSvc::svc
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% MySQLManager::MySQLManager
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% MySQLManager::initConnection
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% MysqlPool::MysqlPool
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% MysqlPool::init
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% MysqlPool::instance
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% Object_Pool::pop
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2   0.3% ProcessDelayMeasure::beginRecvMsg
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% ProcessDelayMeasure::secTillNow
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2   0.3% Receiver::run
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% Sender::append_send_block
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% Sender::process_drop
       0   0.0% 100.0%        5   0.8% Sender::run
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2   0.3% Sender_Watcher::inner_cmd
       0   0.0% 100.0%      297  50.4% Stream_Packer::process_list
       0   0.0% 100.0%      299  50.8% Stream_Packer::run
       0   0.0% 100.0%        2   0.3% Svc_Recv_Handler::handle_input
       0   0.0% 100.0%        3   0.5% Svc_Send_Handler::handle_timeout
       0   0.0% 100.0%        3   0.5% Svc_Send_Handler::write
       0   0.0% 100.0%      581  98.6% Thread::thr_func
       0   0.0% 100.0%       12   2.0% Thread_Mutex::acquire
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% Time_Value::Time_Value
       0   0.0% 100.0%        4   0.7% _IO_default_uflow_internal
       0   0.0% 100.0%        4   0.7% _IO_file_underflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5
       0   0.0% 100.0%      583  99.0% __clone
       0   0.0% 100.0%        4   0.7% __libc_start_main
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% __msync_nocancel
       0   0.0% 100.0%        7   1.2% __pthread_mutex_lock_full
       0   0.0% 100.0%        3   0.5% __pthread_mutex_unlock_usercnt
       0   0.0% 100.0%        4   0.7% _start
       0   0.0% 100.0%        4   0.7% getchar
       0   0.0% 100.0%        4   0.7% main
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% my_connect
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% mysql_real_connect
       0   0.0% 100.0%      583  99.0% start_thread
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% std::_Hashtable::end
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% std::_Rb_tree::find
       0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.2% std::map::find
       0   0.0% 100.0%        3   0.5% thr_sigsetmask (inline)
       0   0.0% 100.0%        3   0.5% ~ACE_Log_Msg_Sig_Guard (inline)
```

Comment: Why do you keep handing your data from one thread to another? That seems bizarre and inefficient.

Comment: How does `write` get called? What does the thread that calls `write` do when there's nothing to write?

Comment: When the logic thread wants to send a package,it will push back to the list,and register that fd output into epoll event.This send thread just sleeps when nothing to process.

Comment: That's probably the problem. The thread shouldn't sleep, it should wait. Lots of calls to `nanosleep` is a giveaway that you're synchronizing your threads very, very poorly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it smells like some kind of synchronization problem.

Some notes from my experience:

That kind of multithreading that you've used is not going to give you the best performance in terms of using whole accessible processing power. First of all because you're using limited number of threads so it won't scale up or down. Second of all because thread synchronization will lower your performance significantly. The best solution that I recommend and tested so far is to use asynchronious sockets with reactor or proactor pattern. You can find some nice explanation within boost::asio library documentation. To improve the code readability and the performance a little you can try to use one of many coroutines implementation ( as far as I know boost::asio allows you to use boost::coroutine now ).

PS. If you could paste some of you're measurement log that would help finding the weak spot in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot.1.I will check thread sync.But it seems wired,because gdb thread apply all bt full,all I see is sleep or condition wait,that means nobody is busy.2.Actually,here use epoll,just like reactor.When to send a package,register the fd handle into epoll event.3.I paste the gprof cpu result.

Comment: To be honest it's just a blind guess. I didn't see the code of your's so it's hard to judge from the sample you've pasted so far. It's just something that came through my mind cause I don't think that any of the operations that you have should eat that amount of time unless you have some other bug i.e. you're not removing processed buffers from the list, check also if you're not using list.length() method cause it has O( n ) complexity in case of std library at least. I've seen that it was a cause of server performance problems many times :)

Comment: Btw. you can try replace list with vector or priority queue if you need to keep an order in your requests. Lists are not too efficient ( in terms of CPU cache mostly ) and you can barely find a use case that they are better than vector.

Comment: I replace std::list with vector,and remove the seperate package thread,do this job in the recv thread now.However,the problem seems unsolved.I could not locate the problem in where.

Comment: In the recv thread,when recv about 2k bytes,it would 20+ ms,does this acceptable?I would like to know how to process the send and recv operation in multiple client connection application,like,using epoll,one thread for send,another for recv?When sending data to some client,just register the handle to epoll.